# How to get number of objects registered in XNA ContentManager?

Tags: interface, xna, content-management-system, xna-4.0

Is there any way to obtain the number of objects registered in the XNA ContentManager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not built into the ContentManager class. But you could increment your own counter that keeps track if you need too.

Comment: Yes, but I think a simple counter would not suffice. For example,the CM does not reload already loaded assets. Furthermore, I am pretty sure that assets that have not been used for a long time are removed from memory at some point.